# angularjs-route not loading with angular --prod flag (angular-cli)

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-cli

Context: I'm migrating from ngJs to ng10, the application runs normally when **I not use the --prod flag**

The thing is: when i use --prod flag the routes doesn't load and i am super clueless why not.
The only difference I see printing the `"next"` attribute on the `$routeChangeStart` is that the `"next"` object on --prod mode doesnt have an attribute called `"locals"`

2nd. weird thing: the `$routeChangeStart` is triggered when i change the URL on the URL bar as it should be, cus the `$routeChangeStart` is printed every time i change the URL

3rd. weird thing: for testing purposes i change `templateUrl` in the config for a `template:'<div>Arcade PvP silly text</div>'` and it doesnt load either, and as far i see, the controller of any view never triggers.

Pls help.

Angular-CLI 10.0.5

Angular 1.7.6 bootstraped over Angular 10.0.6

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I manage to understand more deeply the reasons of this behavior and manage to make a workaround, gonna documentate it here:

1. This is an application made in AngularJS (1.7.x) bootstrapped over Angular 10.0.5
2. Deploying the application with `ng serve --configuration=dev` makes it work as expected after the normal long process of configure the different index.ts and convert everything from *.js to *.ts
3. The reason of the issue is located in the angular.json:

```
{
    "projects":{
        [project_name]:{
            "architect":{
                "build":{
                    "configurations":{
                        "production":{
                            ...
                            "optimization":true <------- THIS
                        }
           ...
}}}}}}
```

The optimization flag effectively makes the bundle very lightweight and `ng build --prod` compiles normally. But as I mention in the question, the problem occurs at runtime: the routes "load" but the HTML never renders for any route configured, therefore ANY of the controllers either runs.

In deep investigation, the `optimization` flag tells the angular-cli webpack to run the minification over the JS, and by past experience, AngularJS seems to be tricky to receive the minifications/uglify processing all due to the `mangle` process, my problem is one of the reasons why.

Angular-CLI's Webpack runs `TerserPlugin` to make the minification and I need to configurate it to avoid using `mangle`, Angular now allows to use a custom webpack configuration file to add rules, this is achieved like this:

1. create a new file in the project base folder, let's say named `custom-webpack.config.js`
2. Reference this file in the angular.json build:

```
{
    "projects":{
        [project_name]:{
            "architect":{
                "build":{
                    "builder":"@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
                    "options":{
                        "customWebpackConfig": {
                            "path": "./custom-webpack.config.js"
                        },
               ...
          }
}}}}}}
```

3. In the file, let's do this:

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                extractComments: true,
                terserOptions: {
                    mangle: false,
                    ie8:false,
                    safari10:false
                }
            }),
        ],
    }
}
```

And voila! The minification occurs, but not the mangle, the application will reduce it's bundle size as expected (mostly) and the angular-route will work normally.